# SQL QUERY to get previous date

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

PERIOD_SERV

```
PERSON_NUMBER           DATE_sTART          PERIOD_ID       
10                      06-JAN-2020         192726
10                      04-APR-2019         12827
11                      01-FEB-2021         282726
11                      09-APR-2018         827266
```

For each person_number I want to add a column with previous date start. When i am using the below query, it is giving me repeated rows.
I want to get only row, with an additional column of the most recent "last date_start". For example -

```
PERSON_NUMBER           DATE_sTART          PERIOD_ID         PREVIOUS_DATE
10                      06-JAN-2020         192726              04-APR-2019 
11                      01-FEB-2021         282726              09-APR-2018
```

I am using the below query but getting two rows,

```sql
SELECT person_number,
       period_id AS pv_period_id,
       LAG(date_start) OVER ( PARTITION BY person_number ORDER BY date_start) AS previous_date
  FROM period_serv
```

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict the set of rows in the outer query

```
select person_number, pv_period_id, PREVIOUS_DATE
from (
  select person_number,
    PERIOD_ID pv_period_id,
    lag(date_start) OVER ( partition BY person_number order by DATE_sTART ) PREVIOUS_DATE ,
    row_number() OVER ( partition BY person_number order by DATE_sTART desc)  rn 
  from period_serv
) t
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `MAX(..) KEEP (DENSE_RANK ..) OVER (PARTITION BY ..)` analytic function such as

```sql
WITH p AS
(
  SELECT MAX(date_start) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY date_start) 
                         OVER (PARTITION BY person_number) AS previous_date,
         p.*                 
    FROM period_serv p                  
)
SELECT p.person_number, p.date_start, p.period_id, p.previous_date
  FROM p
  JOIN period_serv ps
    ON ps.person_number = p.person_number
   AND ps.period_id = p.period_id 
 WHERE ps.date_start != previous_date
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c90b88604aa7d5001fcae906dcf66efc)</kbd>